# MongoDB cursor contains retrieved documents before iterating over it?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

When I executed `find` method and I have a cursor, the cursor contains retrieved documents before iterating over it?

I have this method:

```cs
public async Task<Post> GetPostByIdAsync(ObjectId id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using var cursor = await _Collection.FindAsync(post => post.Id == id, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    return await cursor.SingleAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

First, I'm calling `FindAsync` that returns a cursor, and then, I'm calling `SingleAsync` that returns the document. I have some questions about it.

- In what point the query is executed? When I call `FindAsync` or when I call `SingleAsync`?
- When I executed `find` method and I have a cursor, the cursor contains retrieved documents before iterating over it?
- If I have a cursor with 100 documents, but I only iterate over first 20, the others 80 documents are queried and retrieved from server?
- Why getting the cursor and iterating over it are the two operations async?

```cs
public async Task<Post> GetPostByIdAsync(ObjectId id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var query = _Collection.AsQueryable().Where(post => post.Id == id);
    return await query.SingleAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

- If I call `AsQueryable` because I want to use LINQ, I have only one async method. There are any server operation running sync and blocking the thread?
- I see that `IMongoQueryable<T>` is a subtype of `IAsyncCursorSource<T>`. What is the difference between Cursor and Cursor Source?

Answer (score 0):

When a find is issued and the result set exceeds default (or specified) batch size, the response to the find includes:

- The first batch of documents
- Cursor id to retrieve the next batch

If you know you will only be processing a certain number of documents, use limit to restrict the result set to that many documents.

Comment: But my question is if I only iterate the first batch of documents, are the others documents retrieved from database and stored into the cursor, or the cursor only retrieve documents when the batch is iterated?

Comment: First batch is available in the find response, no further operations are needed.

Comment: D, that is not my question. My question is about I only use for example the three first batches of a cursor that have six batches, are the other three batches queried in the server and transferred over the network?

Comment: No, why would they be?